# How do I trigger azure function which is blob triggered which is already in blob?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure function that is triggered by any new blob (image) that is uploaded to a specific container. These images are then stored on this blob storage container. Now I change something in my function and re-deploy it, I want my azure function to re-run on all these (already stored) images. Since the function is blob triggered, right now I just manually re-upload the same images in the storage container but as image data is increasing it is becoming increasingly infeasible to do so.

Blob trigger in the function looks like this:

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream, doc: func.Out[func.Document]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

    blob_val = myblob.read()
    .
    .
    .
```

What is the solution for it?

Thank you.

Comment: re-run when? And only once or repeatedly?

Comment: Re-run once after deploying the modified function.

Comment: You could create an http triggered function that processes all the blobs again and call this in the azure devops pipeline

Comment: @PeterBons I haven't done that before. can please give an example or a link? I have added what it looks like right now in my code (edited the question).

Comment: I am not a Python expert but you need to create a single function that processes the blobs, and have two azure functions. One that is blobtriggered and one that is http triggered. Have both functions call the python function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't utilize the HTTP request body and then give the value to the blob's input binding. Another option is to include a parameter in your HTTP request and then utilize that parameter in the path of your **blob input bindings**.

If the blob name is not passed correctly in the HTTP request parameter of the function, it will not execute as you would have defined your function as to take **InputStream**.

**HTTP Request URL**: http://{yourfunctionapp}/api/HttpTrigger1?**blobname**=[sample.txt](http://test.txt/)

If that sample text file is not in the container input for the storage account configured, then your function will fail, means returns 500 error if the input blob name is not correct.

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, i*_nputblob: func.InputStream_*) -> func.HttpResponse:
```

**function.json**

```
{
   "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
   "bindings": [
     {
       "authLevel": "anonymous",
       "type": "httpTrigger",
       "direction": "in",
       "name": "req",
       "methods": [
         "get",
         "post"
       ]
     },
     {
       "name": "inputblob",
       "type": "blob",
       "path": "input/{blobname}",
       "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
       "direction": "in"
     },
     {
       "type": "http",
       "direction": "out",
       "name": "$return"
     }
   ]
 }
```

In the alternative, you can only use HTTP input binding, and you'll have to develop your own code to communicate with storage services via HTTP body input.

Comment: How does this address the question?

Comment: Hello @PeterBons, Here I'm using the HTTP Trigger binding to call the existing blob!